# Make tkinter button that calls function below it

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a script that will text you when a product is in stock and I want it to run when you press the start button how ever the function that is supposed to run is below the start button
here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os
import requests
import twilio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from lxml import html
import os
from twilio.rest import  Client



root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg='#263D42')
canvas.pack()




productlink = tk.Entry (root)
canvas.create_window(200, 140, window=productlink)

phonenmbr = tk.Entry(root)
canvas.create_window(500, 140, window=phonenmbr)

productUrl = tk.Label(root, text='Enter Product Url')

productUrl.config(font=('bebas-neue', 14))
canvas.create_window(200, 110, window=productUrl)

phonenumbertext = tk.Label(root, text='Enter Phone Number')

phonenumbertext.config(font=('bebas-neue', 14))
canvas.create_window(500, 110, window=phonenumbertext)

start = tk.Button(root, text='Start Bot', padx=10, pady=5, fg='White', bg='#1E1513', command=stockCheck())
canvas.create_window(350, 150, window=start)

root.mainloop()

account_sid = 'sid'
auth_token =  'auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', "Pragma": "no-cache"}
page = requests.get(productlink, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

def stockCheck():
    while True:
        if soup.find(id='outOfStock'):
                time.sleep(1)
        else:
            publish()
            break

def publish():
    message = client.messages \
                    .create(
                        body="The Product: " + productlink + " Is in Stock BUY IT NOW",
                        from_='+14804057767',
                        to= phonenmbr
                    )
```

the stockCheck function is below the start button and it is hard to move them around because of everything else. Any help?

Comment: First, `command=stockCheck()` will execute `stockCheck()` immediately but it is undefined.  Use `command=lambda: stockCheck()` if it is defined later.  Second, code behind `root.mainloop()` will not be interpreted until the root window is destroyed.  So you need to redesign your code logic.

Comment: also if You don't plan on passing any arguments You could just use `command=func` without the parentheses where `func` is the function You want to call on button press where also You should define the `func` before this so take a look above